Can't push index.ejs file to git hub
I have tried to use "git add ." to add and commit file, but folder "views" is not added.
[the folder is include index.ejs, header.ejs and footer.ejs files.]
I have tried to cd at Views folder and it's work, but it have to cd .. to commit the folder again.
when I checked in my github repository it's show Views folder but I can't open the folder.
and when I tried to clone the project, the file in Views folder doesn't exist too.
I want to know why I can't add, push, open, clone the file. into my github repository.

It might be caused by the .git folder inside your "views" directory. If you see .git folder inside "views" try to remove it and push your code again.

I have found the .git file in views folder and already deleted it, but after i deleted .git, all files don't link with git anymore.
So I decide to delete .git in main folder too. then I reinstall git, and that work!
thank you very much for your advise  that help me a lot :D
